# Blackboard (WebCT) takes ~2 min to load.  Any tricks to make it load faster?

Tags: 10.10, firefox, java

I'm running stock OpenJDK on Ubuntu 10.10 and webCT in firefox loads very slowly.  I haven't found anyone else complaining about this so, I'm wondering how to go about debugging this.  Anyone else have this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed a LOT of folks saying ubuntu 10.10 and openJDK doesn't play nicely with a LOT of things.  I personally am not having problems with SunJDK-i386 on a CHEAP x64 platform (circa $500 hp laptop).  I wish I could help(I think java/jruby is the future of a lot of things).  If someone can pin this down, it would be great.  I think it is largely hardware dependent though.  I am running centrino dual core @ 2.0ish per core with 4GB ram and an nvidia video card on closed source drivers.  To be fair, I have a lot of non-standard packages.

Comment: hp dv-7 is the platform btw

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)